# Using Elasticsearch 2.x how do you pass a DateTime variable to the DateHistogram's ExtendedBounds method?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Nest version 2.1.1, Elasticsearch.Net version 2.1.1
Elasticsearch version 2.3.0

When I used Elastic search 1.3.4 I could  pass strings to my DateHistogram's ExtendedBounds method, since upgrading to 2.3.0 though I only have the option to pass dates in.  Fair enough I thought but at runtime I get this error: **'Time expression 'month' string is invalid.**  If I format my DateTime variables they'll obviously be strings which the method wont accept.

My simplified query being this:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1);                 //31/04/2015 00:00:00
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015 + 1, 4, 1).AddDays(-1);   // 31/03/2015 00:00:00

Query(Query => q..
         ..
         .DateHistogram("my_group", h => h.Field("my_fieldName")
             .Interval("month")
             .MinimumDocumentCount(0)
             .ExtendedBounds(startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: Turns out It wasn't the DateTime variable causing the issue, it was due to how I called the Interval method, it should've been called like this:    .Interval(DateInterval.Month)

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/date-histogram-aggregation-usage.html